# Detect when object not visible to camera (behind another object) - Three.js R71

Tags: html, three.js

I want *intersectObjects* fired when mesh behind another mesh (to detect that mesh is visible to camera or not).

The result that I reached so far is *intersectObjects* fired both when mesh behind and in front of another mesh.

And castRay code:

```
    function castRay() {
        var direction = sphere.position.clone();
        var startPoint = camera.position.clone();
        var directionVector = direction.sub( startPoint );
        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(startPoint, directionVector.clone(). normalize());
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(meshGroup, true);
        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            console.log("hidden");
        } 
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Problem fixed... Need to compare distance between target mesh and intersect mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intersects` is an array of objects in order of ray intersection.

So the first object is `intersects[0]`, the second `intersects[1]`, the third `intersects[2]`, etc. So `intersects[1]` is by definition behind `intersects[0]`.

So if you want to do something with the object in front all you have to do is use `intersects[0]`.

Hope that will help you...